# Why am I getting "'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Checked' ..." here?

Tags: c#, .net

I've found a lot of questions in this topic, but not this one: I'm using c# applications settings, but it's becoming very ugly to save each settings in a new row. I tried to save this with the following code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < settingsTabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.Count; j++)
{
    string currItemName = settingsTabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[j].Name;
    if (currItemName.Substring(0, 7) == "savable" && currItemName == currOptionName)
    {
        if (savableRunAsAdmin.HasProperty("Text"))
        {
            settingsTabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[j].Text = currOptionValue;
        }
        else if (savableRunAsAdmin.HasProperty("Checked"))
        {
            settingsTabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[j].Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(currOptionValue);
        }
    }
}

public static bool HasProperty(this object objectToCheck, string methodName)
{
    var type = objectToCheck.GetType();
    return type.GetProperty(methodName) != null;
}
```

But it says, that

```
'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Checked' and no extension method 'Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can I dynamically save settings, or do I have to save each setting one by one?

Comment: Cast to `CheckBox` or `RadioButton` before setting `Checked`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SelectedTab.Controls` returns a [`ControlCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx) and so the indexer returns a [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/333f9hk4.aspx). You'd need to cast it:

```
((CheckBox)settingsTabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[j]).Checked ...
```

or if it's a `RadioButton` you're after:

```
((RadioButton)settingsTabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[j]).Checked ...
```